# Inconsistent accessibility: Type argument is less accessible than

Tags: c#

I have the following class as below and am getting a warning that says:

`Inconsistent accessibility: Type argument MyNamespace.MyDevices.Device is less accessible than constructor MyNamespace.MyDevices.MyDevices`

```
public class MyDevices
{
    private class Device
    {
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

        public string Model { get; set; }
    }

    private IList<Device> _devices

    public MyDevice(List<Device> devices)
    {
        _devices = devices
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I properly make the class `Devices` only accessible by its parent class `MyDevices`?

Comment: The error is in the error message...

Comment: This design won't work, perhaps tell us what you want to achieve so we can help with a better design

Comment: As D Stanley answered, you're not getting around the accessibility issue. If you want to keep the `Device` class private, then you will have to change your constructor and perhaps your software design. Perhaps external users (those who call your constructor) pass in a different type that is then converted to `Device` objects, or something like that. Of course, my idea might not work within the context of your software, so you'd have to provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I properly make the class `Devices` only accessible by its parent class `MyDevices`?

It has to be accessible to callers if it's a parameter to the constructor - you're expecting the caller to pass in a list of `Device` objects, but `Device` is private.

So either don't make it a constructor parameter or make it public.